# languages: Inability to display one chunk of Mandarin characters, XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, unicode, chinese

I'm using a résumé template which I found online, but am having trouble displaying one short chunk (a company name) of Mandarin characters. I've tried using CJKutf8, as well as xeCJK, without success.

Here is the preamble to the actual résumé:

```
 % !TEX TS-program = XeLaTeX
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Wilson Resume/CV
% XeLaTeX Template
% Version 1.0 (22/1/2015)
%
% This template has been downloaded from:
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
% Original author:
% Howard Wilson (https://github.com/watsonbox/cv_template_2004) with
% extensive modifications by Vel (vel@latextemplates.com)
%
% License:

% CC BY-NC-SA 3.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/)
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[10pt]{article} % Default font size
\usepackage{fontspec}

\input{structure.tex} % Include the file specifying document layout

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}
```

With the `structure.tex` document's preamble being:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Wilson Resume/CV
% Structure Specification File
% Version 1.0 (22/1/2015)
%
% This file has been downloaded from:
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
% License:
% CC BY-NC-SA 3.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/)
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage[a4paper, hmargin=25mm, vmargin=30mm, top=20mm]{geometry} % Use A4 paper and set margins

\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Customize the header and footer

\usepackage{lastpage} % Required for calculating the number of pages in the document

\usepackage{hyperref} % Colors for links, text and headings

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0} % Suppress section numbering

% \usepackage{CJKutf8} <-- **failed prior attempt using \zh{zh-characters}**
% \newcommand{\zh}[1]{\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{gbsn}#1\end{CJK}} <-- **\zh{}**

\usepackage{xeCJK}

\fontspec{~/Desktop/SimSun.ttf}


%\usepackage[proportional,scaled=1.064]{erewhon} % Use the Erewhon font
%\usepackage[erewhon,vvarbb,bigdelims]{newtxmath} % Use the Erewhon font
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for inputting international characters
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Output font encoding for international characters

\usepackage{fontspec} % Required for specification of custom fonts
\setmainfont[Path = ./fonts/,
Extension = .otf,
BoldFont = Erewhon-Bold,
ItalicFont = Erewhon-Italic,
BoldItalicFont = Erewhon-BoldItalic,
SmallCapsFeatures = {Letters = SmallCaps}
]{Erewhon-Regular}
```

And the section of characters that I'd actually like to render being:

```
\job
{xxx 20xx -}{Present}
{xxx (百度), xxx}
{http://www.baidu.com/}
{xxx xxx}
{xxx_details_xxx \\
\rule{0mm}{5mm}\textbf{Concepts and technologies:} xxx}
```

Self-contained example (containing a failed attempt using CJKutf8):

```
% !TEX TS-program = XeLaTeX
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\newcommand{\zh}[1]{\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{gbsn}#1\end{CJK}}

\newcommand{\job}[6]{
\begin{tabbing}
\hspace{2cm} \= \kill
\textbf{#1} \> \href{#4}{#3} \\
\textbf{#2} \>\+ \textit{#5} \\
\begin{minipage}{\smallertextwidth}
\vspace{2mm}
#6
\end{minipage}
\end{tabbing}
\vspace{2mm}
}

\begin{document}

\section{Work Experience}

\job
{xxx 20xx -}{Present}
{xxx (百度), xxx}
{http://www.baidu.com/}
{xxx xxx}
{xxx_details_xxx \\
\rule{0mm}{5mm}\textbf{Concepts and technologies:} xxx}

\end{document}
```

Sorry if there's a bunch in here that's not helpful; I'm relatively new to LaTeX and am still becoming fluent (in terms of what's relevant) :)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please make a self-contained example?

Comment: How do you mean, in terms of self-contained?

Comment: I think I just added one?

Comment: Not really: the question is about using XeLaTeX, but the sample code doesn't run with that engine.

Comment: Sorry for my novice-ness, but could you help me as to a next step?

Comment: The example should at least contain the body of a minimal document and a definition for `\job`.

Comment: Is that better, hopefully? Again, apologies that I'm functionally dragging this out - hopefully these are mistakes  Iwon't make in the future.

Comment: you are loading packages for pdflatex and xelatex at the same time  `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` never use that with xetex (it just gives a warning that it should not be used, and does nothing)
`\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` never use that with xetex, it is forcing the use of font encodings with at most 256 characters so unusable for Chinese.

`\usepackage{fontspec} % Required for specification of custom fonts` this is the one you need, except you have already used `\fontspec{~/Desktop/SimSun.ttf}` some lines above so fontspec is already loaded.